# make on gnu utils - print windows path

Tags: makefile, escaping

I am experimenting with makefiles and trying to create a simple cross platform makefile.

```
PROG = at
INCLUDES = 
LIBPATH = 

ifeq ($(PLATFORM), linux)
obj_ext = .o
CC = g++
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM), winnt)
obj_ext = .obj
exe_ext = .exe
CC = cl
INCLUDES = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
endif

printme:
    echo PLATFORM $(PLATFORM)
    echo Object extension $(obj_ext)
    echo $(INCLUDES)
```

This is giving me the error:

```
>make printme
echo PLATFORM winnt
PLATFORM winnt
echo Object extension .obj
Object extension .obj
echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include'
make: *** [printme] Error 258
```

I don't understand the unexpected token `(' error.  Anyone any ideas why?

My make is:

```
>make -version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
printme: 
    ...
    echo $(INCLUDES)
```

This calls echo with an unpredictable string as its argument. Many magic characters will make the shell behave in unexpected ways. Redirections, wildcards, and then there is `(list)` (in your case: `(x86)`) to execute a list of commands in a subshell.

```
printme:
    ...
    echo '$(INCLUDES)'
```

This should be safe.